# How do I clone a RouteCollection in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

How to do I transfer the items contained in one RouteCollection to another in C# without using foreach?

RouteCollection inherits from Collection< RouteBase >

Comment: Why the constraint to avoid foreach? Considering that .Select(), below, pretty much does the same thing and got accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I made:

```
List<RouteBase> originalRoutes = routes.Select(i => i.Clone()).ToList();
```

To do this I needed two extension methods:

```
public static RouteBase Clone(this RouteBase route)
    {
        if (route.GetType() == typeof(Route))
            return ((Route)route).Clone();
        else
            return null;
    }

    public static Route Clone(this Route route)
    {
        Route cloneRoute = new Route(route.Url, route.RouteHandler);
        cloneRoute.Defaults = route.Defaults;
        cloneRoute.Constraints = route.Constraints;

        return cloneRoute;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CopyTo` function in order to Copies the entire Collection to a compatible one-dimensional Array,

This method uses Array.Copy to copy the elements.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132408.aspx

Comment: but this method copy the collection. I want to clone the list and its elements

Answer (score 0):

You Can try:

```
static void Copy(RouteCollection source, RouteCollection dest)
    {
        Dictionary<string, RouteBase> _namedMap = typeof(RouteCollection).GetField("_namedMap", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(source) as Dictionary<string, RouteBase>;

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = source[i];
            string name = _namedMap.Where(r => object.Equals(item, r.Value)).Select(r => r.Key).FirstOrDefault();
            dest.Add(name, item);
        }
    }
```